# id variable in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

This thing is working:

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT word FROM words WHERE id = 45")
```

How can I make this thing working?

```
my_id = 45
my_cursor.execute("SELECT word FROM words WHERE id = my_id")
```

Comment: Assuming `psycopg2`  the docs spell it out [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: `my_cursor.execute(f"SELECT word FROM words WHERE id = {my_id}")` with **modern** string formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python's Postgres library, you can interpolate values with `%s` and pass them as secondary arguments to `execute`.

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT word FROM words WHERE id = %s", (my_id,))
```